# Tagging: ctrl + [a key]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just noticed that there are [several `ctrl` [space] key tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctrl), for example, `ctrl` `m`, `ctrl` `c`, `ctrl` `alt` `del`. I further notice that `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-v` have been [mapped to `copy-paste`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/copy-paste/synonyms). In addition, the `m` tag, for one, also refers to the `m` language.

I do not think a question regarding `ctrl` and `m`, to take a single example, should have two tags, but does the panel think that each ctrl+character deserves its own tag, `ctrl-m`, which can then be mapped, or should I assign these, when retagging, to a new tag called, perhaps, `ctrl+key` or `ctrl+key-combination`?

This is by no means a large problem, but it is untidy.

Answer (score 1):

IMO those are [metatags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) - useless without other tags, and not describing the content of the question, rather focusing on its accidental properties (describing the action as "*my* installation of `$software` does `$action` when I press `[$that]`", instead of `[$action]`).

Therefore, they should be retagged to the *functionality* - as with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> retagged to `[copy-paste]`: not everybody knows that <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cokebottle</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, when pressed in the SO editor box, invokes the *Summon Unicorn* action, not to mention keyboard shortcut remapping - what does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> do for *you*?

Comment: Wouldn't this limit retagging to people who owned the product in the locale in question? Where can I find the cokebottle key, pls? I am not getting unicorns.

Comment: @Remou: Hm, that's an interesting point - but I wasn't really referring to "what does the text for the action say in $programming_IDE_24.3": I don't care if it says *exactly* "Refactor selected code" or "HIUhsfjoiear", or if it's invoked by pressing Ctrl+Z+Enter while standing on one leg, it is the invoked action that is relevant, no? ( As for the "cokebottle", it is a HHOS name for a character (or a modifier key) you can't type easily, because most keyboards lack it. Refer CATB - this even has a keyboard with *n* modifier keys: http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/space-cadet-keyboard.html )